# How do I add line to .rtorrent.rc using command line in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I am trying to torrent from a specific tracker on my seedbox but haven't been able to successfully connect and was told by a site admin that I should:

> ...disable the verification of certificates. To do so, just add following line to .rtorrent.rc located in your home directory:

The admin then suggested that I could try adding this line to my seedbox (ubuntu) `.rtorrent.rc` file:

```
 network.http.ssl_verify_peer.set=0
```

I am uncertain how to add a line to `.rtorrent.rc`.

I can access the terminal via putty and I can SSH in, it says "Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64) on xxxxxx.xxxx.xx hosted by: xxxxxxx"

Please explain the steps/commands necessary to add the above line to my `.rtorrent.rc` file.